# Achar primeira letra de uma string e deixá-la maiúscula

Tags: php, string

Tenho uma string que poderá começar com letras ou números e preciso deixar a primeira letra dessa string maiúscula. Essa string é aleatória, em cada momento a primeira letra poderá estar numa posição diferente.

> Ex: String: **14ygo3** - Precisa ficar assim: **14Ygo3**

Se a string começar com uma letra eu consegui fazer com o seguinte código:

```
 $string = ucfirst($string);
```

Porém isso não funciona caso a string comece com números.

Comment: se a string for "y14go3", o `ucfirst()` funciona?

Comment: Se a string começar com letra aí funciona, ficando Y12go3

Comment: E se a primeira letra encontrada já for maiúscula, o que acontece? Muda a segunda? Por exemplo, "12Abc", ela permanece igual, ou muda pra "12ABc"?

Comment: Eu imagino que eu teria q percorrer a string até encontrar uma letra, mas não sei como fazer isso

Comment: A string nunca terá letra maiscula pq eu primeiro deixo tudo minusculo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta fazer um loop pelos caracteres da string. Quando encontrar uma letra, mude-a para maiúscula e interrompa o loop:

```php
$str = '14ygo3';

$len = strlen($str);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if (ctype_alpha($str[$i])) { // se é letra
        // converte para maiúscula
        $str[$i] = strtoupper($str[$i]);
        break; // interrompe o for (já encontrei, não precisa continuar procurando)
    }
}

echo $str; // 14Ygo3
```

É bem mais simples e eficiente do que ficar gerando substrings e concatenando-as. A não ser que você não queira modificar a própria string, claro.

---

O código acima resolve para caracteres ASCII. Mas se tiver que tratar letras acentuadas ou quaisquer outros caracteres multibyte, aí pode fazer:

```php
$str = '14ágo3';

function to_upper($m) {
    return mb_strtoupper($m[0]);
}

$str = preg_replace_callback('/\p{Ll}/u', 'to_upper', $str, 1);
echo $str; // 14Ágo3
```

No caso, eu uso uma regex com *Unicode property escapes*: o `\p{Ll}` pega qualquer letra minúscula definida pelo Unicode (incluindo as acentuadas, por exemplo). Depois, eu uso a função `to_upper`, que pega o trecho encontrado e converte para maiúscula. Como o caractere pode ser *multibyte*, eu uso a função `mb_strtoupper`, e por fim, o último parâmetro (`1`) indica para mudar somente a primeira ocorrência encontrada.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!!! Muito obrigado. Esse ctype_alpha q eu nao achava em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente para o que busca. Muito obrigado!